# Worksheet Function with Index/Match

Tags: excel, indexing, match, worksheet-function

I believe my syntax is wrong, would someone mind pointing out the issue?

Thanks in advance

```
 result = Application.WorksheetFunction.IfError(Application.WorksheetFunction.Index_
(Range("Sheet10!$AC$40:$AC$118"), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Range("Sheet10!E3"),_
 Range("Sheet10!$AD$40:$AD$118"), 0)), "")
```

Comment: I don't believe the [IFERROR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-F59BACDC-78BD-4924-91DF-A869D0B08CD5) can be used as a [WorksheetFunction object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834434.aspx). You might try the [Application.Evaluate method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193019.aspx) instead.

Comment: @Jeeped. I just removed the iferror part and still getting the error. Same syntax just removed the all the iferror parts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [IFERROR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-F59BACDC-78BD-4924-91DF-A869D0B08CD5) cannot be used as a [WorksheetFunction object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834434.aspx). The formula will work as long as there is no error but will choke when `WorksheetFunction.IfError` comes into play to return the default value (e.g. zero-length string).

```
Sub ject()
    Dim result As Variant
    'this works if a match is found
    result = Application.WorksheetFunction.IfError( _
                Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Range("Sheet10!AC40:AC118"), _
                Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Range("Sheet10!E3"), Range("Sheet10!AD40:AD118"), 0)), "")
    Debug.Print result
End Sub
```

You might try the [Application.Evaluate method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193019.aspx) instead.

```
Sub jective()
    Dim result As Variant
    'this works on match or no match
    result = Application.Evaluate("IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet10!AC40:AC118, " & _
                "MATCH(Sheet10!E3, Sheet10!AD40:AD118, 0)), ""nothing"")")
    Debug.Print result
End Sub
```

Typically, there can be `Application.Index(...` or `WorksheetFunction.Index(...` but there is no need for `Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(...`.

When referring to a static cell address with a string, there is usually no need for the **$** absolute makers since a string is not going to change. One possible exception would be when you are using the string to fill a large number of cells with a formula; not getting the result from evaluating a single formula.

Comment: BINGO. I ended up changing it slightly to get it to work (having an in sheet error validation and just have the vba code return contents of cell) but I did try this and it worked. Thanks very much